# short for: bar != null ? 'foo$bar' : null

Tags: dart

Is there a shorter more idiomatic way to implement the ternary null check expression to set the picture?

```
final ownUser = User(
  id: user.id,
  displayName: user.displayName ?? 'Anonymous',
  picture: user.avatarId != null ? '${apiBase}/avatars/${user.avatarId}' : null,
);
```

This logic is quite common on a daily basis and our code base would benefit a lot readability if we could express this in a more idiomatic way, especially removing to state `null` twice ((1) in the condition and (2) as the result in the else case). But I wonder if any operator even get's rid of the `null`, e.g. something like this

read: "null or this expression"

```
picture: user.avatarId ?:! '${apiBase}/avatars/${user.avatarId}',
```

Comment: I dont know how dart does it, but normally if something is null, it would return False when checking for a boolean. Therefore shorter would be `picture: user.avatarId ? ${...} : null`

Comment: @gXLg `null` is not implicitly convertible to a boolean in Dart.

Comment: No, there isn't really a better way to express that ternary expression.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27716 for a request to make such constructs nicer.